# QProcess with GUI not freezing

Tags: qt

I would like to launch mysql from GUI using `QProcess`. I've tried the following:

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << QString("-u%1").arg("myaccount")<<  QString("-p%2").arg("password");

QProcess *mysql = new QProcess;
mysql->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
mysql->execute("mysql", arguments);

if(mysql->waitForReadyRead(-1))
    qDebug(mysql->readAllStandardOutput());
```

But, there is big problem as it's mentioned in Qt Documentation, it's gonna freeze.
How can I solve this? Many advised to use `QThread` but I don't have any idea how to do that?
Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call the `QProcess::execute()` function and it waits until the process is finished. If you need to avoid freezing you can use `readyReadStandardOutput()` signal and do the following:

```
[..]
connect(mysql, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readOutput()));
mysql->start("mysql", arguments);
if (!mysql->waitForStarted()) {
    // report error
}
```

Comment: Well, Thank you! Also, how can I prompt warning message box when mysql password or user account entered wrong. After connecting readyReadStandardOutput() signal it's gonna be problematic for me to detect this issue. Can you help?

Comment: @elgolondrino, I think that depends on how `mysql` reports about incorrect username/password input: exits with error code, prints out error message to standard output or standard error?

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you:
[QProcess fails to execute external executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074826/qprocess-fails-to-execute-external-executable)

Calling MySQL :
c:\mysql\mysql.exe -u MYUSERNAME -pMYPassword

There is no space between -p and password.
Set MySQL Path.