# Qt program freezes every time

Tags: c++, qt, freeze

I'm making a C++ GUI program in Qt using qtcreator its not complete yet but when ever I build and run to test the program it runs then if i click buttons that open a file or write something in a file, the button does that and then the program freezes. Why this happens, What I'm doing wrong or what's the issue.
It mainly freezes in theses two functions:

```
    void MainWindow::on_kmpOpenButton_clicked()
{
    QString kmplayerloc = "\"F:\\Program Files\\The KMPlayer\\KMPlayer.exe\"";
    QProcess::execute(kmplayerloc);
}

void MainWindow::on_nbopenbutton_clicked()
{
    // Remember tha if you have to insert " in a string  \"....location of file or anything u want to put.......\"
    QString netbeansloc = "\"F:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.4\\bin\\netbeans.exe\"";
    QProcess::execute(netbeansloc);
}
```

Comment: show your code, otherwise we're helpless

Comment: I think what you want is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074826/qprocess-fails-to-execute-external-executable

Comment: @cageman No Qprocess works and both applications start but then the program freezes and windows gives not responding error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html)

> Starts the program *program* [..] in a new
>   process, **waits for it to finish**, and then returns the exit code of the
>   process.

The calling thread freezes until the external process is finished. If you don't want this, use the method `start` or `startDetached`.